# using slash in Perl Command

Tags: perl, replace, find, slash

Below the command i want to run.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's//apps/LIVE/appl/xx/11.5.0//$XXTOP//g;'  prog.txt
```

Here, source and replacement both have slashes in them.

How to handle this?

--
Update

I tried with curly braces and tilde  that was suggested.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's{apps/LIVE/appl/xx/11.5.0}{$XXTOP}g;'  prog.txt
```

In this case, Dollar sign in giving issue, else it works fine..

```
Error: 
Name "main::XXTOP" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value at -e line 1, <> chunk 1.
Use of uninitialized value at -e line 1, <> chunk 2.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use another delimiter:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's~/apps/LIVE/appl/xx/11.5.0/~$XXTOP/~g;'  prog.txt
```

You could access environment variable thru `%ENV`, like:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's~/apps/LIVE/appl/xx/11.5.0/~$ENV{XXTOP}/~g;'  prog.txt
```

Comment: Error: 
Name "main::XXTOP" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value at -e line 1, <> chunk 1.
Use of uninitialized value at -e line 1, <> chunk 2.

Comment: -w is 'causing' the warning, and it's telling you that the variable $XXTOP has not been previously defined.  Since it's a one-liner, where do you expect that value to come from?

If you want the actual $ symbol in the replacement, escape it using a backslash.  ie: s~/apps/LIVE/appl/xx/11.5.0/~\$XXTOP/~g;

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the text `$XXTOP` to appear in the output. In which case escape the $ - `{\$XXTOP}`

```
perl -pi -w -e 's{apps/LIVE/appl/xx/11.5.0}{\$XXTOP}g;'  prog.txt
```

Perl is thinking that `$XXTOP` is a Perl variable.

Of if you are want to expand an environment variable, use `$ENV{$XXTOP}`

Answer (score 0):

solved:
Solution:

perl -pi -w -e 's{apps/LIVE/appl/xx/11.5.0}{\$XXTOP}g;'  prog.txt